# How can I write an ICS file for the Friday before the first Saturday of the month?

Tags: icalendar

I've seen [How can an ICS file be written for a recurring event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455376/how-can-an-ics-file-be-written-for-a-recurring-event) but I've got a rather complex recurrence and can't figure out a rule after looking at [the syntax](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-8-5-3-recurrence-rule.html) of RRULEs.

I want an event that happens on the Friday preceding the first Saturday of each month. This *Friday-before-the-first-Saturday* may of course be in the previous month. I assume that if I can get this to work, similar (but not identical) events for *Friday-before-the-second-Saturday*, and *-third-* and *-fourth-*, with Friday before 5th Saturdays undefined.

Obviously I'd have `RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=FR;` but if I try to follow some of the examples using `BYMONTHDAY` I run into trouble: `28` would be a valid *Friday-before-a-first-Saturday* in February, but in any other month, Friday 28th would be the Friday before a **5**th Saturday. Similarly for `29` (in a leap year), `30` and `31`.

The goal is to include this in a Google Calendar, which I know supports display of ICS RRULEs it can't edit.  So, assuming it's possible, how can I create an RRULE for this event? I've considered a separate event and accompanying rule for each month length. 31: Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct, Dec and 30: Apr, Jun, Sep, Nov are OK, but leap years are still an issue: 28 Feb could be a Friday before a first Saturday or a 5th Saturday (e.g. 2020 so one of my first two cases fails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with having to use BYDAY=FR, AND since you can do negative BYMONTHDAY, the following should do the trick:

RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=FR;BYMONTHDAY=-1,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: Thank you.  I was embarrassingly close to getting it but got hung up on leap years.  Now to fight gcal's import which seems to wipe one event when I import a second...

Comment: Hi Chris, make sure you are using a different unique UID for each event https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.7

Comment: You got it in one! Copy-pasting doesn't work, but at least I figured that out for myself.